Question about store CSRF token in cookies
I'm starting a new project and have encountered some issues with CSRF. My setup includes React for the frontend, Servlet for the backend, and Spring Security version 6.0.1.
In my WebSecurityConfig.java, I’m storing the CSRF token in cookies:
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
            .build();
}

In App.js, I have a getter function, but it’s failing. I checked the console, and document.cookie returns ''. However, I found the XSRF-TOKEN cookie in Chrome’s Inspect tool under Application > Cookies > [my front-end URL].
const getCSRFTokenFromCookie = () => {
    const name = "XSRF-TOKEN=";
    const decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);

    const cookieArray = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(let i = 0; i < cookieArray.length; i++) {
        let cookie = cookieArray[i].trim();
        if (cookie.indexOf(name) === 0) {
            return cookie.substring(name.length, cookie.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
};

My observations are as follows:
When I disable CSRF, my app works as expected.
When CSRF is enabled:
My UI automatically calls doGet requests without issues, and the CSRF token is not stored in cookies.
When I call doPost, it results in a 403 Forbidden error. I can see the XSRF-TOKEN cookie in Chrome’s inspection tool, but document.cookie remains empty.
My questions are:

Why is document.cookie returning an empty string even though the XSRF-TOKEN cookie is present in Chrome’s Inspect tool?
How can I ensure that the CSRF token is accessible in the document.cookie for use in my frontend

